# A good ubuntu alternative for rufus

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a windows user and I am new to ubuntu. I use rufus on windows to create bootable usb drives from iso images of oses. What is a good ubuntu software for doing that?

Link to rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: What's wrong with Startup Disk Creator, already included with most flavors of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use Etcher (https://etcher.io/) since it seems to perform slightly faster than the built-in Startup Disk Creator, however I've never had any issues with the Startup Disk Creator and have used that reliably as well.

In my opinion if you're just making a new bootable USB once or twice a year to keep an Ubuntu install USB up-to-date with major releases, why not just use the convenient tool provided natively? If you're in some sort of situation where you need to make tons of bootable USB sticks for some reason you might benefit from the slightly higher performance of Etcher. Although if you really need to make **lots** of bootable USBs for some reason, you should probably look into specialized software/hardware, which I can't comment on as I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Etcher with good success.

I also like 'WOEUSB'.

In WoeUsb, once 'Target Device' is selected, unmount the device from Nautilus before clicking 'Install'

Reference: [[1]:  "Download and info for WoeUsb"](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/tool-to-create-bootable-windows-usb.html#more)